# How to add responsive class to ckeditor image dialog?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, colorbox

I have website baker that has CK Editor.
I want to have images automatically have the class "img-responsive" if no classes are inserted.
How? Can i Do that

I cant find a dictionary of this http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Default_Field_Values
what names are every input and so on? and the html source wont show that.

Comment: any fiddle to help us knowing more about the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem long time ago. I probably copy-pasted most of the code and I did some minor modification by myself. Its a bit long code, which add `img-responsive` class to all added images.

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {

        //resp. images for bootstrap 3
        ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
                {
                    elements:
                            {
                                $: function(element) {
                                    // Output dimensions of images as width and height
                                    if (element.name == 'img') {
                                        var style = element.attributes.style;
                                        //responzive images

                                        //declare vars
                                        var tclass = "";
                                        var add_class = false;

                                        tclass = element.attributes.class;

                                        //console.log(tclass);
                                        //console.log(typeof (tclass));

                                        if (tclass === "undefined" || typeof (tclass) === "undefined") {
                                            add_class = true;
                                        } else {
                                            //console.log("I am not undefined");
                                            if (tclass.indexOf("img-responsive") == -1) {
                                                add_class = true;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        if (add_class) {
                                            var rclass = (tclass === undefined || typeof (tclass) === "undefined" ? "img-responsive" : tclass + " " + "img-responsive");
                                            element.attributes.class = rclass;
                                        }

                                        if (style) {
                                            // Get the width from the style.
                                            var match = /(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style),
                                                    width = match && match[1];

                                            // Get the height from the style.
                                            match = /(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style);
                                            var height = match && match[1];

                                            if (width) {
                                                element.attributes.style = element.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                                                element.attributes.width = width;
                                            }

                                            if (height) {
                                                element.attributes.style = element.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                                                element.attributes.height = height;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }



                                    if (!element.attributes.style)
                                        delete element.attributes.style;

                                    return element;
                                }
                            }
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did this below and it works perfect:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

    $( "img" ).addClass( "img-responsive" );

});
```

ps: I am on rails 5 which explains the 'turbolinks:load'

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a simpler solution - once the page loads, just loop through the images and add an 'img-responsive' class to the child 'img' elements within your parent div ('article' in my case).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('article').children('img').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('img-responsive');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine jquery script. I use it with Bootstrap. I warp all the img into an div and copy the width property to the parent div to set the max-width, and copy the float. In this case I can set the size of the image and still will be responsive plus I can set the float from CKEDITOR.

```
function changeImg() {

    var hirmegjelenito = document.querySelector('.hir-megjelenito');
    var imgs = hirmegjelenito.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
        $(imgs[i]).attr('class', 'img-fluid');
        $(imgs[i]).wrap("<div class='container p-0' style='float:" + $(imgs[i]).css("float") + ";max-width:" + $(imgs[i]).css("width") + ";margin:" + $(imgs[i]).css("margin") + "'></div>");
        $(imgs[i]).css({
            "height": "auto",
            "max-width": "100%",
            "width": "",
            "float": "",
            "margin": "0px 0px 0px 0px"
        });
    }
    return imgSrcs;

};
```